# MySQL Embedded SELECTs vs. JOINs

Tags: mysql, query-performance

Is there a noticeable difference between:

```
SELECT userid, username, userdept,
    (SELECT deptname FROM depts WHERE deptid=userdept) AS deptname
    FROM users
```

and

```
SELECT userid, username FROM users
    INNER JOIN depts ON depts.deptid=users.userdept
```

Which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query has better performance.

You can see this example: http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2008/7/31/MySQL-performance-INNER-JOIN-vs-subselect

Answer (score 1):

join is better ,

see this link  :
http://www.selikoff.net/2008/12/10/memo-avoid-nested-queries-in-mysql-at-all-costs/

Answer (score 1):

you can see the [many discussion in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=subquery+vs+join) on this topic as well.

Answer (score 1):

These two queries are not synonyms.

They would be the synonyms if you replaced the `INNER JOIN` with the `LEFT JOIN`, with the exception that the subquery is a subject to failure if `deptid` is not unique, while a `LEFT JOIN` will always succeed.

If there is a `UNIQUE` index on `depts.deptid` (which most probably is, since this field is most probably a `PRIMARY KEY`), then the performance difference would be negligible.