# which one run faster in mysql

Tags: performance, mysql

which one run faster in mysql:
a query with multiple joins or that query with using nested select?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131368/mysql-embedded-selects-vs-joins

Comment: @meagar: at the link you provided it's quite definite correlated subquery and the same join, so it's possible to make decisions. but here there are no additional details to say something specific or point to any specific thread, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the correct Indexes on the tables, I would go with saying `JOINS` would be more performant, **but** *it is always best practice to test the various queries for performance*.

Answer (score 5):

it's impossible to answer in this case. you should analyze each of them with `EXPLAIN`

Comment: here is the query:(it returns 60,000 records)

SELECT  @row := @row + 1 AS rowno,t2.no,t3.fname,
                t3.lame,t2.syear,
                t2.fcode ,t2.flcode,t2.pid
                FROM t2
                JOIN t3 ON t3.pid=t2.pid
                JOIN t4 USING(stid)
                JOIN t5 ON t4.ecode=t5.ecode
                WHERE t5.cat='1' 
                ORDER BY t3.lname,t3.lname
all tables have indexes.
i haven't tested nested select yet.

Comment: Please post a new question... I imagine it's taking a while doing a filesort of 60k records, it will depend on the row size and many other factors, please post a new question with the query, schema of all tables and the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases, JOINS are more efficient.  This assumes you're joining on columns which are indexed.  HOwever, the above answers are right.  You need to evaluate your particular query with EXPLAIN to see.